# CGPDFViewController and multipage PDF (zomming)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, cgpdfdocument

I am trying to create a basic PDF viewer for iOS, and I am pretty much stuck. I only want it to be able to view PDFs and jump to a specific page.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
#import "SFPDFViewerController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation SFPDFViewerController
@synthesize currentPageIndex;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    currentPageIndex = 1;

    myDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/soulstorm/Desktop/Basic%20UNIX%20Tutorial.pdf"]);
    myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocumentRef, currentPageIndex);
    //CGRect pageRect = CGRectIntegral(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox));
    CGRect pageRect = self.view.bounds;

    CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
    tiledLayer.delegate = self;
    tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0);
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 1000;
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 1000;
    tiledLayer.frame = pageRect;

    myContentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect];
    [myContentView.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
    viewFrame.size.height-= 44;

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.contentSize = pageRect.size;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    [scrollView addSubview:myContentView];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return myContentView;
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    NSLog(@"draw layer...");
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, myPageRef);
}

#pragma mark - Functions
- (IBAction)goToNextPage:(id)sender
{
    [self displayNextPage];
}
- (IBAction)goToPreviewsPage:(id)sender
{
    [self displayPreviewsPage];
}

- (void)displayNextPage
{
    currentPageIndex++;
    [self reloadCurrentPage];
}
- (void)displayPreviewsPage
{
    currentPageIndex--;
    [self reloadCurrentPage];
}
- (void)reloadCurrentPage
{
    NSLog(@"reloading current page... %i", currentPageIndex);
    myPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(myDocumentRef, currentPageIndex);
    //[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    //[self.view.layer setNeedsDisplay];
    //[myContentView.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}
#pragma mark -
- (void)dealloc
{
    [myContentView release];
    myContentView = nil;
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(myDocumentRef);
    myDocumentRef = NULL;
    myPageRef = NULL;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

The above code displays the first page of the PDF corectly, but when I try to go to the next page, it will remain on the first one, and sometimes when zooming I can see parts of the second page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer provides a simple example. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html